# Why it doesn't have @Inject for dependency injection?

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger

I am reading some code and have trouble understanding

```
import dagger.Component
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import javax.inject.Inject


class Sound(val noise: String)

class Dog @Inject constructor(val sound: Sound)

@Module
class DogModule() {
    @Provides
    fun provideWoWo(): Sound = Sound("wowo")

    @Provides
    fun provideDog(sound : Sound): Dog = Dog(sound)
}

@Component(modules = [ DogModule::class ])
interface AnimalComponent {
    val dog: Dog
}

fun main() {
    val component = DaggerAnimalComponent.create()
    println("The dog has sound ${component.dog.sound.noise}.")
}
```

why `class Sound(val noise: String)` without `@Inject`?

I thought it would be
`class Sound @Inject constructor(val noise: String)`

since `Sound` class instance is also created via dagger just like `Dog` class instance

Answer (score 0):

Because you explicitly set the `@Provides` with constructor parameter. `@Inject` is used to omit the `@Provides`. In your code the `@Inject` on `Dog` can be removed as well.

To sum up - you don't have to add `@Inject` if you are creating this class with `@Provides`

Comment: Never knew you could omit @Inject. I was trying to google it but couldn't find any docs, could you share a link with me? Thanks

Comment: @GigiWithoutHadid I don't think i can provide you with the link about that, i know that from experience, but i'm not sure where did i got this information from. `@Provides` is manual way of injecting class, `@Inject` is annotation that is automating this process

Answer (score 0):

> since Sound class instance is also created via dagger just like Dog class instance

This isn't correct: Neither `Dog` nor `Sound` is being *created* via Dagger. Dagger allows `Dog` and `Sound` to be injected, but in the Module you are *creating the instances* in the `@Provides` methods/functions you define.

This also means that `@Inject` annotations for both `Dog` and `Sound` are currently ignored, because Dagger is not a part of the construction of those objects. Instead, you are providing those yourself: `@Provides` methods and functions can receive objects in the graph, which Dagger will provide, and that's how you are receiving `Sound` as part of the `@Provides Dog` method. As a consequence, if `Dog`'s constructor argument list were ever to change, you would need to change the `@Provides` method yourself. Dagger also won't automatically populate `@Inject`-annotated methods and fields, labeled in the docs as "method injection" and "field injection".

If you were to delete the `@Provides` method for `Dog`, then Dagger would read the argument list itself and react automatically when it changes. Method and field injection would also work automatically then.

As a consequence, you never need to use `@Provides` on a class with an `@Inject` constructor unless you want to override or customize the arguments passed into the constructor. I recommend using `@Inject` wherever possible and reserving `@Provides` only for code you don't control or for other special cases. See my other SO answer here: [Android Dagger 2: Inject versus Provides](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39207845/1426891)